# Insert / Select query

Tags: php, select, mysqli, insert

Having trouble with the following query.  Can anyone help coach me along?

Two tables:  `wa_list` and `wa_research`.

`wa_list` is my standing table, `wa_research` is my staging table and once my research is complete I want to move those records researched to the `wa_list` table and update a column `"wa_research.updated"` to today's date in the format `MM-DD-YYYY`

```
INSERT INTO `wa_list` (exchange, symbol, security_name)
SELECT A.exchange, A.symbol, A.security_name
FROM `wa_research` A WHERE A.waID != 0 AND A.CIK = 0;
```

There are more fields, I just truncated them for simplicity.  I'm thinking I can do it all in one query, but looking for a sanity check and guidance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting now? That looks like it should work. Can you show the whole query and table structure?

Comment: use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: @AlivetoDie why, it's only a single query?

Comment: You can create a trigger to update the `wa_research.updated` column after the insert to the `wa_list` table though it looks like you might want to include some common value (ie a foreign key) so you can reference the correct record

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response...The following query works, but just trying to determine how in the same sequence I an update the wa_research.updated with the date.   

INSERT INTO `wa_list` (exchange, symbol, security_name)
SELECT A.exchange, A.symbol, A.security_name
FROM `wa_research` A WHERE A.waID != 0 AND A.CIK = 0;

The idea of a trigger could work, just have not worked with those before so I can go and try, but wanted to clarify what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Would anyone be willing to revisit this question that I have?  The INSERT INTO  part works great, being able to then at the same time update the `wa_research.updated` field to MM-DD-YYYY is what I am still missing.  I think this can be done in one query, just missing the perspective if that is correct and then maybe the general syntax or an example of what I as looking to do.

Answer (score -1):

What is A in last line near the WHERE. It maybe the error. Put the error you getting.

## Or use this

```
UPDATE
wa_research war,
wa_list wal
SET
war.columnName= wal.columnName
WHERE
war.columnName= SOMEVALUE;
```

Comment: `A` is the alias OP has given to the `wa_research` table